# svn: can't export Thumb.db file

Tags: svn, export

I'm programming an automatic file uploader from svn to ftp and i'm getting an error with this file: **Thumb.db**

When i export the folder works fine:

```
svn export -r 100 --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username user --password passwd http://reporul/projectname/trunk/public_html/application/helpers/pqp/images/ --force
```

result:

```
A    images
A    images/overlay.gif
A    images/Thumbs.db
A    images/side.png
Exported revision 100.
```

When i export some file from this folder works fine:

```
svn export -r 100 --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username user --password passwd http://reporul/projectname/trunk/public_html/application/helpers/pqp/images/side.png --force
```

result:

```
A    side.png
Export complete.
```

but with **Thumb.db**:

```
svn export -r 100 --non-interactive --no-auth-cache --username user --password passwd http://reporul/projectname/trunk/public_html/application/helpers/pqp/images/Thumb.db --force
```

i get this error:

```
svn: E160013: '/projectname/!svn/bc/18032/trunk/public_html/application/helpers/pqp/images/Thumb.db' path not found
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need thumbs.db version-controlled? I'd recommend ignoring it.

Comment: I don't need this file, but maybe can get same error with other file